# Creating searching functionality in php page for html content

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a php page which displays the F5 pool member status. I would like to create a search bar so that when you start typing something, it displays the pool name and pool member only with the text that has been typed. Can someone please recommend ?

Here is the part of the php code which displays the pool and member status-

```
 echo "<center><table cellspacing='6' cellpadding='6' width='100%' 
  border='0'>";
  echo "<tr><th><font size='6'><b>Pools</b></font></th></tr>";
  echo "<tr><td valign='top' width='50%'>";
  foreach ($pool_list as $index=>$pool)
  {
     $pool_name=trim($pool,"/Common/");
     echo "<center><a name='$pool'></a>";
     $availability_status=$poolstatus[$index]->availability_status;
     $img = getgif($availability_status);
     echo "<img src='$img'><b> &nbsp $pool_name</b>";
     echo "<table border='1' cellpadding='5' width='100%'>";
     echo "<tr>";
     echo "<th bgcolor='#ADD8E6' width='25%'>Member IP</th><th bgcolor='#ADD8E6' width='25%'>Member Name</th><th bgcolor='#ADD8E6' width='25%'>Enable Status</th><th bgcolor='#ADD8E6' width='25%'>Current Connections</th></tr>";
     foreach ($memberlist[$index] as $member_index=>$member_value)
     {
        $address=$member_value->member->address;
        $name=$client3->get_screen_name(array($address));
        if ($name[0] == "") { $name[0]=$address; }
        $port=$member_value->member->port;
        $member_name=trim($name[0],"/Common/");
        $sess_status=$member_value->object_status->availability_status;
        $enabled_status=$member_value->object_status->enabled_status;
        $mon_status=$membermonlist[$index][$member_index]->monitor_status;
        $stats=$client2->get_statistics(array($pool),array(array($member_value->member)));
        $ccount=$stats[0]->statistics[0]->statistics[4]->value->low;
        $tcount=$stats[0]->statistics[0]->statistics[6]->value->low;
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td bgcolor='#F5F5DC' align='center'> &nbsp $address</td>";
        echo "<td bgcolor='#F5F5DC' align='center'>$member_name</td>";
        $img = getgif_member($sess_status, $enabled_status);
        echo "<td bgcolor='#F5F5DC' align='center'>";
        echo "<img src='$img'>";
        echo "</td>";           
        echo "<td bgcolor='#F5F5DC' align='center'>$ccount</td>";
        echo "</tr>";
     }
     echo "</table>";
  }
```

Comment: If you just want "searching" within your existing html table, look at DataTables (javascript)

Comment: Thank you Tim. What if I have multiple html tables and I would like to display only tables which matches the searching criteria?

Comment: That would be much more complicated and involve searching the pool (however you're obtaining it) and then figuring out how to display the results.  Although.... perhaps you could do some fancy javascript which observes your search field and then passes the search term to each table.  If you pursue that, I would suggest making a change in the way you approach displaying the page:  try to separate all your logic from your presentation, and when you do your presentation, do it as html with php added, not as php printing stuff out.  It makes the javascript much easier.